# How to add HttpSessionEventPublisher for logout in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a Spring Boot version of Pet Clinic overriding as little of Spring Boot defaults as possible.

At this point, my logout link doesn't seem to work and I've been told that it is because I haven't properly added `HttpSessionEventPublisher` to my application.

How can I add `HttpSessionEventPublisher` to my application?

I've tried the following:

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class WebXmlConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> getHttpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

My main class does not extend any classes. If that is required for me to add `HttpSessionEventPublisher`, I would need to know which class also.

None of the Spring Boot examples log out properly, so I have nothing to based on off of.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would the event publisher do that you don't get from Spring Security logout handlers out of the box?

Comment: You are configuring HttpSecurity with something like http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout.htm").logoutSuccessUrl("login.htm")? You shouldn't need more than that.

Comment: I also have this:
`http...logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
.and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).expiredUrl("/login?expired");`

I log out but can't log back in. Every post points to registering `HttpSessionEventPublisher` as a servlet listener, but I need to do it in JavaConfig, not XML, and I can't find a way to do it that actually works for me.

See my [WebSecurityConfig](https://github.com/arnaldop/enhanced-pet-clinic/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/ui/config/WebSecurityConfig.java)

Comment: Shouldn't the code in the comment above have handled it?

Comment: Your code with `ServletListenerRegistrationBean` is correct. Maybe you forget to add `@Configuration` to the class containing the `@Bean`?

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938308/how-to-configure-sessionlistener-use-spring-boot-1-x