# How to configure sessionListener use spring boot 1.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot.
Now ,I want to add a listener. 

e.g `public MySessionListener implement HttpSessionListener`
How to configure `SpringApplication`?
Can I use `SpringApplication.addListener()` or other way to do it? Please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are referring to are listeners for Spring context life-cycle. That is not what you want.

[Spring boot documentation states](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-and-filters):

> When using an embedded servlet container you can register Servlets,
>   Filters and all the listeners from the Servlet spec (e.g.
>   HttpSessionListener) directly as Spring beans. This can be
>   particularly convenient if you want to refer to a value from your
>   application.properties during configuration.

UPDATE:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

@Bean
public HttpSessionListener httpSessionListener(){
    // MySessionListener should implement javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener
    return new MySessionListener(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had misunderstood addListener method. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @telebog. Added simple example how to register Spring bean

Comment: You are missing a return on that method

Comment: This saved my day! Thanks!